# ItemLoader in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I can't seem to get the ItemLoader to work. I don't get any errors in the scrapy log, just nothing gets extracted. Any ideas would be helpful!

```
import scrapy
from medium.items import MediumItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

class DataSpider(CrawlSpider):
    custom_settings = {
         'LOG_FILE': 'my_log.log',
         'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR'}
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    name = 'data'
    allowed_domains = ['medium.com', 'towardsdatascience.com']
    start_urls = ['https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/02/01']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def parse(self,response):
        articles = response.xpath('//div[@class="postArticle postArticle--short js-postArticle js- 
                                 trackPostPresentation js-trackPostScrolls"]')
        for article in articles:

            if article.xpath('.//a[@class="button button--smaller button--chromeless u-baseColor-- 
                              buttonNormal"]/@href').extract_first():
                l = ItemLoader(item = MediumItem(), selector = article)
                l.default_output_processor = scrapy.loader.processors.TakeFirst()
                l.add_css('Title','div > h3::text')
                l.add_xpath('Name','.//a[@class="ds-link ds-link--styleSubtle link link--darken link- 
                             -accent u-accentColor--textNormal u-accentColor--textDarken"]/text()')
                l.add_css('Read','span::attr(title)')
                l.add_xpath('Publication', './/a[@class="ds-link ds-link--styleSubtle link--darken 
                             link--accent u-accentColor--textNormal"]/text()')
                l.add_xpath('Claps','.//button[@class="button button--chromeless u-baseColor-- 
                          buttonNormal js-multirecommendCountButton u-disablePointerEvents"]/text()')
                l.add_xpath('Responses','.//a[@class="button button--chromeless u-baseColor-- 
                             buttonNormal"]/text()')
                l.add_value('Page',response.url)
                yield l.load_item()
```

The Items file is

import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

```
class MediumItem(Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Date = scrapy.Field()
    Read = scrapy.Field()
    Publication = scrapy.Field()
    Claps = scrapy.Field()
    Responses = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: you can use `print()` in code to see valus in variable and check which part of code is executed. Maybe it couldn't find your `xpath` so it never run `ItemLoader()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At start I get two problems

1. it needs

   ```
   Page = scrapy.Field()
   ```
2. page `https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/02/01` is redirected to `https://medium.com/tag/python/archive` but it is blocked by

   ```
   handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
   ```

   After removing `handle_httpstatus_list` I get data from first page

Result (csv)

```
Claps,Date,Name,Page,Publication,Read,Responses,Title
81K,,Daniel van Flymen,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,9 min read,383 responses,Learn Blockchains by Building One
25K,,Jonny Fox,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,6 min read,63 responses,Regex tutorial — A quick cheatsheet by examples
9.6K,,Susan Li,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,9 min read,112 responses,"Building A Logistic Regression in Python, Step by Step"
5.8K,,Adi Bronshtein,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,9 min read,46 responses,Train/Test Split and Cross Validation in Python
7.8K,,Will Koehrsen,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,21 min read,42 responses,Random Forest in Python
7.2K,,Ted Petrou,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,24 min read,34 responses,Selecting Subsets of Data in Pandas: Part 1
11.1K,,Milo Spencer-Harper,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,6 min read,86 responses,How to build a simple neural network in 9 lines of Python code
5.2K,,Michael Galarnyk,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,8 min read,27 responses,PCA using Python (scikit-learn)
64K,,TK,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,11 min read,148 responses,Learning Python: From Zero to Hero
6.9K,,Susan Li,https://medium.com/tag/python/archive,,9 min read,75 responses,An End-to-End Project on Time Series Analysis and Forecasting with Python
```

---

Code which I used - all in one file without creating project

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

class MediumItem(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Date = scrapy.Field()
    Read = scrapy.Field()
    Publication = scrapy.Field()
    Claps = scrapy.Field()
    Responses = scrapy.Field()
    Page = scrapy.Field()

class DataSpider(CrawlSpider):
    custom_settings = {
         'LOG_FILE': 'my_log.log',
         'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR'}
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    name = 'data'
    allowed_domains = ['medium.com', 'towardsdatascience.com']
    start_urls = ['https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/02/01']
    #handle_httpstatus_list = [302]

    def parse(self,response):
        print('url:', response.url)
        articles = response.xpath('//div[@class="postArticle postArticle--short js-postArticle js-trackPostPresentation js-trackPostScrolls"]')
        for article in articles:

            if article.xpath('.//a[@class="button button--smaller button--chromeless u-baseColor--buttonNormal"]/@href').extract_first():
                l = ItemLoader(item = MediumItem(), selector = article)
                l.default_output_processor = scrapy.loader.processors.TakeFirst()
                l.add_css('Title','div > h3::text')
                l.add_xpath('Name','.//a[@class="ds-link ds-link--styleSubtle link link--darken link--accent u-accentColor--textNormal u-accentColor--textDarken"]/text()')
                l.add_css('Read','span::attr(title)')
                l.add_xpath('Publication', './/a[@class="ds-link ds-link--styleSubtle link--darkenlink--accent u-accentColor--textNormal"]/text()')
                l.add_xpath('Claps','.//button[@class="button button--chromeless u-baseColor--buttonNormal js-multirecommendCountButton u-disablePointerEvents"]/text()')
                l.add_xpath('Responses','.//a[@class="button button--chromeless u-baseColor--buttonNormal"]/text()')
                l.add_value('Page', response.url)
                yield l.load_item()

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(DataSpider)
c.start()
```